# Your server didn't allow connect with our API for validate the license

Tags: curl, opencart

So I have bought one extension for Opencart VPS to import products from excel or other formats. Extensions works if I upload file manually, however it cannot get info from file if it's uploaded to my server (where website is hosted). I am facing an error:

```
CURL ERROR NUMBER: 6
```

`Your server didn't allow connect with our API for validate the license. Put in contact with your hosting support team, they have to solve this external problem. This extensions is doing a simple CURL call to domain https://devmanextensions.com (217.61.128.42).`

So I am not PRO at this. I have VPS server running with Linux (Ubuntu v16). How I can "whitelist" or what I have to do to let my server connect to this IP ?

Firewall on server is disabled - did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.
There was a problem with link provided where the server should access.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).